# Two instance of React caused by injected script

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

In our production environment a script is injected by a third party which breaks our application with [React Error 321](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=321) and indeed when I run this in the console `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers` I see that there are two renderers, with the same version number. I suspect that this third party script is the where the second instance of React is created but I would like to know for sure. Is there any way to find out where this second React instance is coming from?

```
[
    {
        "key": 1,
        "value": {
            "bundleType": 0,
            "version": "16.14.0",
            "rendererPackageName": "react-dom",
            "overrideHookState": null,
            "overrideProps": null,
            "setSuspenseHandler": null,
            "scheduleUpdate": null,
            "currentDispatcherRef": {
                "current": {}
            },
            "findHostInstancesForRefresh": null,
            "scheduleRefresh": null,
            "scheduleRoot": null,
            "setRefreshHandler": null,
            "getCurrentFiber": null
        }
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "value": {
            "bundleType": 0,
            "version": "16.14.0",
            "rendererPackageName": "react-dom",
            "overrideHookState": null,
            "overrideProps": null,
            "setSuspenseHandler": null,
            "scheduleUpdate": null,
            "currentDispatcherRef": {
                "current": {}
            },
            "findHostInstancesForRefresh": null,
            "scheduleRefresh": null,
            "scheduleRoot": null,
            "setRefreshHandler": null,
            "getCurrentFiber": null
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error (`You might have more than one copy of React in the same app`)
Can you move reactJs & react-dom to `peerDependencies` the `package.json` of imported package ?

```
 "peerDependencies": {
    
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  },
```

Comment: It already is a peerDependency :/

Comment: with exact same version ?

Comment: "react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",